# Could Not Find Boost Static Libraries: Log_Setup and Thread

Tags: c++, boost

I am attempting to install boost 1.67.0 with the static libraries `boost_log_setup` and `boost_thread`.

I have followed [the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) to build boost from source on my Mac running OS Catalina 10.15.

I ran the following command to link the static libraries specified: `./b2 --link=static --with-log --with-thread`

I also ran that command without the `--with` directives, doing a full statically-linked build (or possibly doing nothing at all, the result is the same). `./b2 --link=static` and `./b2 --link=static install` and `./b2 install` all failed to install the necessary libraries.

I haven't found anything about `boost_log_setup`, so I have to assume it means `log`, which is probably related to why I can't pass the makefile checker.

The makefile of the project I am attempting to build is still unable to find `boost_log_setup` and `boost_thread` with this check:

```
set(_Boost_LOG_SETUP_HEADERS           "boost/log/detail/setup_config.hpp")
set(_Boost_THREAD_HEADERS              "boost/thread.hpp")
```

It does specifically tell me it cannot find those two, which means it is correctly reading my `BOOST_ROOT` directory at `/usr/local/boost_1_67_0`.

Can someone help me build this flaming dumpster fire of a project?